# Cannot access static functions in mongoose model . the error says "unexpected token . "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I have my mongoose schema defined in user.js file.

```
   //user.js

 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const  validator = require('validator');
 const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 email: {
   type:String,
   require:true,
   trim:true,
   minlength: 1,
   unique:true,
   validate:{

   validator: validator.isEmail 
   ,

   message: '{value} is not valid',
 }

 },

 password:{
   type:String,
   required:true,
   minlength:6
 },
 tokens: [{
   access:{
     type:String,
     required:true
   },
   token:{
     type:String,
     required:true
   }
 }]



   })
  userSchema.statics.findByToken = function(token){


  console.log('token');


   let User = this;
  console.log("this is: ",User);
  let decoded;

  try{
  decoded = jwt.verify(token,'abc123')

  }catch(e){



     return Promise.reject();

  }


   return User.findOne({
   _id: decoded._id,
   'tokens.token': token,
   'tokens.access': 'auth'
    })

     }

   const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema );
  module.exports = {
  User: User,

  }
```

I am trying to import it into a seperate file and call the function findByToken inside `app.get("users/me") route` . The function is meant to receive the token as an argument and find the document associated with that token from the database.
 The code is pasted below

```
   //server.js

   const express = require('express');

    const {User} = require('./models/user.js');
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

  let app = express();
 app.use(bodyParser.json());



    process.env.port = 3000;
   const PORT = process.env.port;

   app.get('/users/me',(req,res)=>{ 
   let token = req.header('x-auth')


  User.findByToken(token).then((user)=>{

   if(!user){
  return Promise.reject();
  }

  res.status(200).send(req.user);
   }).catch(e)=>{
 res.status(401).send();
   }


   })

   app.listen(PORT,()=>{
   console.log('listening to port: ',PORT)
   })
```

When I run the code I get this error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post code instead of screenshots? It is much easier to read

Comment: please post your code instead of screenshots, code is easy to read.

Comment: sorry, I have posted the code . Thanks

Comment: `const {User} = require('./models/user.js')` should be `const User = require('./models/user.js');`

Comment: i tried, but did not work :/

Comment: Try changing the exports to `module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);`  here users is the name of the document in mongodb. Replace with the name you have used. In the current export, there's no mention of userSchema, so the other scripts do not know what model User refers to and what methods it has

Comment: Or at least `module.exports = {
  User: userSchema
  }` a way to tell others that User is related to userSchema

Comment: @Alwin did it help?

Comment: it was the problem with my catch statement. it should be `catch(e=>{
 res.status(401).send();`

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

I don't see an export expression in your user.js

Comment: `const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema );

module.exports = {
  User: User,
  


}
` . I do have an export expression

Comment: @Alwin, as requested before, please post code instead of screenshot. Please post complete code, right from where you declare the model